# Read a String as XML in .NET 2.0

Tags: xml, vb.net, .net-2.0

I have a `string` that is coming from DB. I would like to read this as `XML`. String looks like below

```
<settings>
  <setting name="OfferIDs" value="47,48,49,50,51,52,53,76,77,78,79" />
  <setting name="someothersetting" value="" />
  <setting name="anothersetting" value="" />
</settings>
```

I would like get the value of `OfferIDs` as a string using VB.NET. Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without access to LINQ, your code would look like this...

```
Dim xmlDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
xmlDoc.Load("YourXmlFile.xml")
Dim OfferIDs As String = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//settings/setting[@name='OfferIDs']").Attributes("value").Value
```

That should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: To use .NET 2, I'd probably use `XmlDocument`:

```
Dim document = new XmlDocument()
document.LoadXml(xml)
```

You'd then need to navigate through the document looking for the appropriate element by its `name` attribute, then take the `value` attribute of that element. I'm rusty on `XmlDocument` these days, but hopefully that's enough to get you started...

---

The simplest way is probably to load it with LINQ to XML:

```
Dim settings = XElement.Parse(xml)
```

... and then query it. It's easy in C# but my VB-fu is failing me for the LINQ query part.

The C# would be something like:

```
XElement settings = XElement.Parse(xml);
string offerIds = settings.Elements("setting")
                          .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "OfferIDS")
                          .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("value"))
                          .Single();
```

Comment: Unfortunately cannot use LINQ as solution is on .NET 2.0, but many thanks for the reply

Comment: @Chin: In the future, it would be worth mentioning that in the question. I tend to assume at least .NET 3.5 these days, given how long it's been out. Editing...

Comment: sorry about that.. will do in the future.

Comment: @Chin: No problem. I've left the original answer in case anyone needs it in the future, but the top of my edited answer should help you in .NET 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringReader` combined with `XmlReader` (fast, non-cached, forward-only access to XML data) to read xml from string.
In C# :

```
string source = GetXmlAsString ();
using (StringReader xml = new StringReader (source)) {
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create (xml)) {
        while (reader.Read ()) {
            if (reader.IsStartElement ("setting")) {
                string attrName = reader.GetAttribute ("name");
                if (attrName == "OfferIDs") {
                    string attrValue = reader.GetAttribute ("value");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In VB :

```
Dim source As String = GetXmlAsString()
Using xml As New StringReader(source)
    Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xml)
        While reader.Read()
            If reader.IsStartElement("setting") Then
                Dim attrName As String = reader.GetAttribute("name")
                If attrName = "OfferIDs" Then
                    Dim attrValue As String = reader.GetAttribute("value")
                End If
            End If
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```